# What is the correct disassembly for ARM opcode E1F322D1?

Tags: disassembly, arm

I'm adapting the [reko decompiler](https://github.com/uxmal/reko) to use Capstone for its disassembler, instead of rolling my own. I'm using the .NET bindings provided by [Capstone.NET](https://github.com/9ee1/Capstone.NET).

The strategy is to replace the old ARM disassembler with the Capstone disassembler and then run the old unit tests to make sure nothing broke. I'm at a point where most test are passing, but the opcode `E1F322D1`, which both the old reko disassembler and ODA disassemble to:

```
 ldrsb r2, [r3, #33]!
```

But, Capstone responds with:

```
ldrsb r2,[r3,#&221]!
```

I don't have other disassemblers handy, so I'm uncertain who to trust!

What's the correct disassembly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDA agrees with the first one:

`LDRSB           R2, [R3,#33]!`

Capstone might be trying to display something like #0x21, which would be equivalent, but it seems that something went wrong.

Comment: Indeed, after some further troubleshooting I narrowed down the problem to Capstone.NET and reported it. Hopefully a fix will be forthcoming soon.

Answer (score 6):

From http://bear.ces.cwru.edu/eecs_382/ARM7-TDMI-manual-pt2.pdf:

[image: LDRSB]

`E1F322D1` equals `11100001111100110010001011010001` in binary.

Your question is specific to the offset, so we can examine the last dozen bits of that binary string with regard to the decomposition rules in the screenshot above:

```
... Offset 1 SH 1 Offset
...  0010  1 10 1  0001
```

Thus, the high nibble is `0010` and the low nibble is `0001`. If we combine them, we get `00100001` in binary, or `33` in decimal.

So the correct disassembly is `ldrsb r2, [r3, #33]!`.